# Jquery slide up function not activating in contact form script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, slideup

Everything is working on this contact form except for the last bit using the slide up function to replace the contact form with a thank you message and I just can't seem to hack my way to a solution.

You fill out the form, hit submit, the email gets sent, and the loading gif appears, but the slideup animation never happens and the thank you image never shows.

```
<!--CONTACT PANEL-->
<div id="contact-panel">

    <div class="top">: : CONTACT ME : :</div>

    <form id="contactform" method="post">
        <ol class="forms">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name:" required minlength="2" /></label>
            </fieldset>
                <p style="margin-top: -10px;"><label for="name" class="error"></label></p> 
            <fieldset>
                <label for="email"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email:" required /></label>
            </fieldset>
                <p style="margin-top: -10px;"><label for="email" class="error"></label></p>           
            <fieldset>
                <label for="message"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Question/Comments:" required ></textarea></label>
            </fieldset>
                <p style="margin-top: -5px;"><label for="message" class="error"></label></p>            
            <li class="buttons"><button type="submit" id="submitemail">Send Email &raquo;</button><input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" /></li>

        </ol>
    </form>

</div>
```

Here's the JS...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "*Please enter your name.",
                minlength: "*Your name must consist of at least 2 characters."
            },
                email: "*Please enter a valid email address.",
                message: "*Please, say something at least 10 characters long.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#submitemail').hide();
            $("#contactform li.buttons").append('<img src="media/contact/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');      
        $.post('code/form-contact/submitcontactform.php',
        $('form#contactform').serialize(),
        function(data){
            $("#contactform").slideUp("normal", function() {                                                
            $("#contactform").before('<img src="media/contact/contact_thankyou.png" alt="Thank You" id="thankyou" />');     
            });         
        });         
        },      
    })      
    return false;                          
});
```

I have tried a lot of different ways but I just don't know enough beyond guessing and trial and error. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Have you verified that the function containing the slideUp call is running, say with a console.log statement?

Comment: Try doing the slideup before the $.post to see if it's a problem with post.

Comment: Are you using some plugin??

Comment: With firebug, I see this error `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`....Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in messages json as below:

```
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "*Please enter your name.",
            minlength: "*Your name must consist of at least 2 characters."
        },
        email: 
        {
            email: "*Please enter a valid email address.",
            required: "Please enter email address."
        },
        message: 
        {
            minlength: "*Please, say something at least 10 characters long.",
            required: "Please enter message"
        }
    },
```

to make it work in fiddle, I had to remove post call as jsfiddle doesn't support it:

http://jsfiddle.net/shifatullah/v3dTz/16/

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a genius....I just had to iron out a couple of syntax issues once I re-introduced the post call....but everything works now as it should! Thanks again!